# Jquery Mobile Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I am trying to create a dialog popup message that displays an image when index is being loaded on a mobile device. I just need to make this popup show up just when the page is being loaded.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a div with the attribute `data-role="popup"`, then when you want to use it `$('#popupID').popup("open");` to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by setting it outside of `$document.bind` with a setTimeout. I don't understand enough to know why `$('#myPopup').popup("open")` doesn't work inside $document.bind. Here is how it works for me:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
setTimeout("popupForm()",10);
});

function popupForm() {
    $('#popupLogin').popup("open"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
            //execute code to show pop-up immediatly in-line, assumes jquery library has already been loaded and the "popup" DOM element is already defined:
            $("#mypopup").show();

            //set handler to dismiss popup on window loading
            $(window).load(function() {
                  $("#mypopup").hide();
            });

    </script>
```